# Multitouch Openscenegraph and Qt

Tags: qt, multi-touch, surface, openscenegraph

I have a Qt application with an integrated OSG scene.
The problem is that Multitouch events are not working correctly
on my Surface-Tablet.

Maybe they are not forwarded to the Qt-Widget which holds the OSG scene.

One finger touch works fine like you would use the left mouse-click.

Zoom gesture is not working very good. Your two fingers needs to be on the screen for a bit of time ~ 1 sec, then it works not very user conform, also it switches the direction of zoom.

Drag gestures are not working at all it will just zoom.

Has anyone an idea where the problem is?

Is the problem in the osgQt sources (GraphicsWindowQt)?
Could it be a problem with the Surface Pro 3 Tablet?
Or is it maybe more a problem with the MultiTouchManipulator?